# Why jdbc encoding utf-8 not working?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, encoding, utf-8

I have problem with encoding. When I use only the main (testing) method of this class, output is fine

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.print("Default Charset=" + Charset.defaultCharset());
System.out.println("testing ńńńń");

}
```

Output is : 
Default Charset=UTF-8
testing ńńńń

but when I use this class according to the purpose, encoding fails! some code:

```
public class MySQL {
    public static Connection connect(){
    try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/flats?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8","root","****");
    }catch(Exception e){
    throw new Error(e);
}}

public static long selectPrice(Connection c, String city){
    try{
        PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement("" +
                "SELECT price FROM flatlist" +
                "WHERE city=? " );
        ps.setString(1, city);
        System.out.println(ps);
        System.out.println("Default Charset=" + Charset.defaultCharset());
        System.out.println("ńńńńńńń");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    rs.close();
    ps.close();
    }
```

And i receive the output :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@19cff046: SELECT price FROM flatlist WHERE city='????'  
Default Charset=ISO-8859-1  
???????
```

this MySQL class is connected with jsp file. But on the website I am able to provide the utf8 characters, also page reads from request utf8 characters.

Comment: Why do you believe `Charset.defaultCharset` is relevant? What does that have to do with the JDBC connection?

Comment: Instead of sending onto a console, write into a file and see if the output still has issues?

Comment: Charset.defaultCharset() has nothing in common with your database.
First check (with command line client) if your database/table supports UTF-8

Comment: jw23, yes DB has already filled rows with UTF characters.